# If...would...would construction

Tags: conditional-constructions

> I would really, really appreciate it if you would kindly leave comments or make corrections.

I thought the if-clause in such a construction takes a past subjunctive like:

> if I were you, I would choose the red one
>
> I would buy a doll if I went to that city

But in the sentence above two *would*s were used.

Is it different from:

> I would appreciate it, if you left comments.

Could you please describe the rule.

Comment: *If* doesn't actually take the simple past.  Consider "If he comes here, he will find us".  Look up the *subjunctive* - this might be a useful page: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/subjunctive-verbs

Comment: @stangdon thanks, I said about if-part in if--would constructions, I know with *will* its different.

Answer (score 2):

> I would appreciate it, if you *left* comments.
>
> I would appreciate it, if you *would leave* comments.

With **left** we have backshifting of tense to mark the statement in the if-clause as a possibility, not an actuality.

With **would leave** we have a modal periphrasis of the same idea.

The main clause refers to a future contingency, and thus we don't say "I *will* appreciate it" but "I *would* appreciate it."

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't get the difference! you say the first is a possibility, what is the second? not a possibility?

Comment: Neither one is an actuality but something which, if it were to occur, would receive the speaker's appreciation.  Both are an invitation to leave comments as well as a statement about how such comments would be met, if they were to be left.  The comments do not yet exist.