# If you would not date yourself

Tags: conditional-constructions, conditionals, if

A current trend on TikTok is captioned: "If you would not date yourself, you should lower your standards."

The sentence makes sense to me and seems grammatical. However, I keep telling people that more often than not *would* in the if-clause is technically wrong, but here I can't seem to find anything wrong with it. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Possibly the same as [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/104177/if-would-would-construction).

Answer (score 1):

I found an explanation in Martin Hewings' *Advanced Grammar in Use.*

"We don't usually use if ... will in conditional clauses. However, we can use if ... will in requests [I knew about that; if + would for a polite request] **or with the meaning 'if you are willing to'** [...]

This fits the given example:
*If you would* [as the simple past of will in this type II conditional with a hypothetical/impossible condition] *not* [i.e. If you are not willing to] *date yourself, you should* [modal verb used for conditional I constructions, so this should be a mixed conditional] *lower your standards.*

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: As you posted this as an answer, this question is no longer appears as open (maybe half open as the answer is not accepted). I think you should delete it and put this to the question by editing it.